# use a gif as pano source in react-vr

Tags: react-360

I have an animated gif that I would like to use as the source for a 'pano' element or similar. Is this possible?

I guess an alternative may be to create a simple looping movie but as I have the gif already I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GIF but it will not animate. Converting it to a video and using the VideoPano component is your best bet.